# Dynamodb ttl actual time of removal

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have setup TTL on dynamodb table and enabled a stream.  According to aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) it can take up to 48hrs before item is removed. I have run some experiments and I am seeing a 10min delay.  I can live with this but has anyone else had longer delays?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

There are instances where the time taken for the item removal to happen takes more than 10 mins! In fact, the [SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ttl-dynamodb/#:%7E:text=Resolution,without%20consuming%20any%20write%20throughput.) from DynamoDB is 48 hours. The time needed for the actual removal to happen `depends on the activity levels of DynamoDB tables`.

Answer (score 0):

A more pointed rephrase of [Allan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809720/85269):

Even if no one has seen that delay (and chances of finding it anecdotally through a Q&A site seems like a bad statistical test) Amazon says to expect the possibility of that much of a delay. This is for resource cleanup only, and most likely a breach of the 48h SLA will only allow you a refund of storage costs.

**Do not depend** on the absence of a given item to trigger logic within your application (e.g., user session timeout).